# Mesa crocus driver not being used on Debian

Tags: debian, gnome-shell, mesa

I have an i7-5500U chip (which I think means it's 5th gen) with Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09). I use Debian unstable and a few weeks ago the `libgl1-mesa-dri` package got updated from 21.3.8-1 to 22.1.3-1. At this point, the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so` driver disappeared and my GNOME Shell performance degraded. I decided to pin the version of `libgl1-mesa-dri` (and some related packages) to 21.3.8-1 in order to fix the problem. However, there are now more and more packages that can't be upgraded so I'm trying to resolve the problem properly by switching to the new `crocus` driver which apparently is the correct driver for this chip.

After removing my apt pin settings and completing the package upgrades, I can see that the `crocus` driver shared object exists in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so`.

I've set the environment variable: `MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=crocus` in `/etc/environment` and I've checked that `gnome-shell` has this variable in its environment:

```
$ cat /proc/{pid}/environ | tr '\0' '\n'|grep MESA
MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=crocus
```

But my GNOME Shell is still performing badly with CPU spikes whenever anything needs to render.

I can see that it's still apparently using software rendering:

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 14.0.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.1.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears
libGL: MESA-LOADER: dlopen(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so)
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/user/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/user/.drirc: No such file or directory.
```

I get the same output if I run `glxinfo` or `glxgears` setting `MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=crocus` on the command line.

When GNOME Shell starts up I get the following log messages:

```
gnome-shell[914]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.2) as a Wayland display server
gnome-shell[914]: Device '/dev/dri/card0' prefers shadow buffer
gnome-shell[914]: Added device '/dev/dri/card0' (i915) using atomic mode setting.
gnome-shell[914]: Failed to initialize accelerated iGPU/dGPU framebuffer sharing: Not hardware accelerated
gnome-shell[914]: libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
gnome-shell[914]: libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
gnome-shell[914]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card0'
gnome-shell[914]: Boot VGA GPU /dev/dri/card0 selected as primary
gnome-shell[914]: Initialized single buffered shadow fb for HDMI-1
gnome-shell[914]: Initialized single buffered shadow fb for eDP-1
gnome-shell[914]: Disabling DMA buffer screen sharing (not hardware accelerated)
gnome-shell[914]: Using public X11 display :0, (using :1 for managed services)
gnome-shell[914]: Using Wayland display name 'wayland-0'
```

But I haven't been able to work out what these are telling me.

So how I can get `gnome-shell` to use the `crocus` Mesa driver for my GPU? Or perhaps there's some other way to get hardware acceleration working again for `gnome-shell` for my GPU?

Comment: It looks like there's a proposal to package the older drivers for Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1006202. So this might be an alternative solution for me when it's available.